# If a program is open, close it

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying various methods of closing programs if they are open, but can only get the third method to work.

```
if WinExist("ahk_exe exe.exe")
    WinClose
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
if WinExist("Partial Window Title")
    WinClose
if WinExist("Window Title")
    WinClose
```

Comment: Are you sure all those windows/executables are both running, and under those names?

Comment: Also you can't use `WinExist`  to close background processes, as it only allows to close current _windows_.

Comment: That will be why: the programs associated with the other methods are minimised to the system tray. Is the Process command the only alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the process you are trying to kill is not a background process.

If it is, try using `Process`

Example:

```
Process, Exist, exe.exe
if (Errorlevel != 0)
    Process, Close, exe.exe
```